# Avatar command in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hello I am creating a discord bot and I'm making the avatar command. When I make on myself (without mention), it works. But when I mention someone nothing happens

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");


module.exports = {
    name : 'avatar',
    description : "commande pp",
    execute(message, args) {


        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        let avatar = user.displayAvatarURL({size: 4096, dynamic: true});


    
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Avatar de ${user.tag}` )
        .setURL(avatar)
        .setImage(avatar)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription('Ton avatar :')
        message.channel.send(embed)

    }
}
```

Comment: This part of your code works fine, there is no error in this. If you say `message.author` works when there's no mentioned user, it should also work when you mention someone. You should do some basic debugging; check if the code runs when you mention someone, check the value of `user` and `avatar` etc.

Comment: Let me know if my solution fixed your Problem

Comment: yeaah thank you it worked

Comment: @Cryopt hi its me again. Would you mind clicking that little check mark on my answer? So people know that this question has been answered and resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.
Usage:

`avatar` sends the iamge of the author of the message

`avatar @user`  sends image of mentioned user

```js
var discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name : 'avatar',
    description : "commande pp",
    execute(client, message, args) {

       let user = message.author;
       let avatar;

       //when args are given, set user to mentioned user
       if (args.length > 0) {
           let userID = args[0].slice(3, -1)
           user = message.guild.members.cache.get(userID).user;
       }

       avatar = getUserAvatar(user);


       let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setTitle(`Avatar de ${user.tag}`)
           .setURL(avatar)
           .setImage(avatar)
           .setColor('RANDOM')
           .setDescription('Ton avatar :')
       message.channel.send(embed)
   }
}


//This returns the AvatarURL of the user
function getUserAvatar(user) {
    let avatar = user.avatarURL()

    return avatar;
}
```