# Why discord.js avatar command give low resolution pic?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I make an avatar command but it works but it give e low-resolution pic
example [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJYTF.png)

My Code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'avt',
  description: "Used of user avatar",
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setImage(user.avatarURL({size: 2048,
            dynamic: true, }));
    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020219/10926046) answers your question

Comment: Changing the size can alter how it looks. You could just leave it as default

Answer (score 1):

You should try chaning the image format to PNG or JPG. Don't worry, if the avatar is animated, the format will automatically be set to GIF.

If the image remains in low resolution, try changing the size to 4096.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'avt',
  description: "Used of user avatar",
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const avatarEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0x333333)
        .setAuthor(user.username)
        .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', size: 2048, dynamic: true }));
    message.channel.send(avatarEmbed);
  }
}
```